# "IndexOutOfRangeException" Error. Any ideas why?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have this code in my app code

```
using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["data.user"].ToString()))
{
    oConn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, oConn))
    {
        oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@J_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
        oCmd.Parameters["@J_ID"].Value = JobID;

        using (SqlDataReader drJobDetails = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (drJobDetails.Read())
            {
                Jobs oJob = new Jobs();
                oJob.JobIDNumber = 1;
                oJob.JobID = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_ID")] as string;
                oJob.JobTitle = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_Title")] as string;
                oJob.JobShortDescription = "";
                oJob.JobDescription = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_Description")] as string;
                oJob.JobLocation = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("BDS_Name")] as string;
                oJob.JobHREmail = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_HREmail")] as string;
                oJob.JobDateAdded = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_DateAdded")] as DateTime? ?? default(DateTime);
                oJob.JobUserAdded = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_UserAdded")] as string;
                oJob.JobCloseDate = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("BJ_ClosedDate")] as DateTime? ?? default(DateTime);
                oJob.JobDateUpdated = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_DateUpdated")] as DateTime? ?? default(DateTime);
                oJob.JobUserUpdated = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_UserUpdated")] as string;
                oJob.JobActive = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_Active")] as int? ?? default(int);
                oJob.JobVideo = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_Video")] as string;
                return oJob;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: J_Video]
```

If I remove the J_Video it works fine so not sure what could be the issue with it.
I'm quite new to SQL and C# so any hint towards why this error is coming up would be great!

Comment: Apparently there is no `J_Video` column in what stored proc returns

Comment: [IndexOutOfRangeException : The name specified is not a valid column name.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: can we see the contents of `strQuery`

Comment: @MariaL Check to make sure your stored procedure is returning that column in the database

Comment: @MariaL I more meant the actual SQL - if its a stored procedure try pasting the content of the SP here too.

Comment: Thanks everyone- I checked the SP and the issue was in there so thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that the DataReader does not have a column names `J_Video`. That column is refered to in this line:

```
oJob.JobVideo = drJobDetails[drJobDetails.GetOrdinal("J_Video")] as string;
```

Check your query `strQuery` to see if this column is selected (`SELECT J_Video, ... FROM ...`) and make sure it is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the Query is returning the J_Video column. I think the query is not returning it.